# Extract timecode per frame

Tags: video, timecode

I have 2 video clips and their start time differs in a few seconds, as in the first camera started recording at 13:20:35, and the second camera started the recording at 13:21:00. 
These cameras have a syncbac attached to it which inserts timecode into the mp4 stream. I want to extract the timecode from the mp4 and then trim the 25 seconds from the first video so that the timecode on the starting frame of each video is EXACTLY the same.

So basically - I want the first frame of both the videos to have the EXACT timecode.

Any suggestions how to get this? I am guessing ffprobe or ffmpeg is the solution, but any exact command?

Comment: Timecode is stored for the first frame along with the frame rate. It's not stored per-frame.

Comment: Oh is it? What command is used to extract that? Please advice. Thanks :)